Reference request - Density of smooth functions in Sobolev space with zero trace on part of boundary
I have a question regarding a mathoverflow remark in a thread Density of smooth functions in Sobolev space, respecting nonnegative traces.
There it is written that it is a known result in the theory of Sobolev spaces, that smooth functions vanishing on some part $\Gamma_0 \subset \partial\Omega$ of the boundary $\partial\Omega$, are dense in the set $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with functions vanishing on $\Gamma_0$.
Could someone give me a reference to this statement or is it just copying the proof of density of smooth function in eg. $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ where one would only have to estimate an additional boundary term on $\Omega\setminus \Gamma_0$ that can be easily estimated by definition of the trace?
Many thanks for any feedback.
